# How would I enable partial search and case ignore in Cloudant Search Index?

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

Search function

```
function (doc) {
  for(var j =1;j<doc.sheets[1].data.length;j++){
      index("Name", doc.sheets[1].data[j]);    
  }
}
```

My analyzer is standard. How would I modify this function so as to achieve search with partial matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to use `*` and other from special characters as part of the query syntax to perform wildcard searches, fuzzy searches, etc.

from https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/search.html#query-syntax:

> If you want a fuzzy search, you can run a query with `~` to find terms like the search term. For instance, `look~` finds the terms `book` and `took`.

and

> Wildcard searches are supported, for both single (`?`) and multiple (`*`) character searches. For example, `dat?` would match `date` and `data`, whereas `dat*` would match `date`, `data`, `database`, and `dates`.